# Add a title to my select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to put a title to my `select_tags`
I would like to have something like `Select a user` and then all the users appear below... for now I have the name of the first user... I don't want that... 
Any suggestion? I can't find anything working with my view...

thanks for your help

```
=form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =select_tag :select, options_for_select(User.order('nickname ASC').all.map{|u| u.nickname}, params[:select])
        =submit_tag "Select", class:"btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`include_blank`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) option:

```
select_tag :select,
           options_for_select(User.order('nickname ASC').all.map{|u| u.nickname}, params[:select]),
           { include_blank: 'Select a user' }
```

Other option is to use `prompt`. See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) for more available options of `select_tag`.

Comment: I tried couple of things but didn't find what expected... maybe I didn't ask myself the good question ;)

Comment: @Nelly-Johan well, right question is a half of the job ;) Be aware, that you only can accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,  add prompt option to the select_tag

```
=select_tag :select,
options_for_select(User.order('nickname ASC').all.map{|u| u.nickname},
params[:select]), prompt: "Select a user"
```

Comment: It works well too !! many thanks ! I will accept the answer  too !!

Comment: @Nelly-Johan, welcome buddy, You can accept only one answer per question

Comment: you have not accepted any answer yet, you just upvote it, please accept any of the answer so that it will help somebody else .

Comment: I will accept yes but it said you can only accept in "4min".... so... i will soon